# VSCode - wrong way of line separations in code formatting

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, format

I'm using the latest version (1.29.0) of VSCode to work on my Angular 6 project (typescript files, of course).
When I format the code in a .ts file, each component under an "import" command is displayed on a separate line (regardless of the amount of imported components/modules, even if there's just one).

For example:

```
import {
     Component,
     OnInit,
     Input,
     ViewChild,
     ViewChildren,
     QueryList,
     ElementRef
}
from "@angular/core";
```

How do I disable that, and get all of this in one line??

Btw, the following code appears in one line, though:

```
import * as Types from "@cc/my-types";
```

Moreover, there are places in the code where the formatter locates the ";" char in a separate line after an object definition.

For example:

```
interface myObject {
     prop1: {
          id: number;
          type: number;
          inner: {
               inner_inner: {
                    prop11: number;
                    prop22: number;
               }
          }
     }
     ;
     data: {
          id: string;
          type: string;
          groupId?: string;
          name: string;
          isSelected: boolean;
     }
     ;
}
```

Comment: Do you have the prettier extension (or similar installed)?  If so, disable it and see if the reformatting still occurs.

Answer (score -1):

> When I format the code in a .ts file, each component under an "import" command is displayed on a separate line

Neither TypeScript, nor VSCode do this by default.

## Solution

Disable all extensions in vscode and then enable them one by one to find the culprit. Then remove the culprit, or read its docs.

Most likely its `vscode-prettier`.